# iOS 13 & Xcode 11 - UINavigationBar broken scrolling for large titles

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, ios13

On iOS 12 and Xcode 10.3 I had no problems with the large titles scrolling, but with the same code, Xcode 11 and iOS 13, I encounter the problem as shown in the following GIF:

[image]

While on iOS 12 I had the navigation bar with the desired behaviour, which is this:

[image]

Did someone encounter the same problem? For the rest I'm of course using the `prefersLargeTitles = true` and I'm sure the code I'm using it's the same for this 2 different behaviours. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for it after some investigation, so I'll share my findings since I think can help some people. 
The solution is that, from iOS 13, we have to work with the `UINavigationBarAppearance`. Once we have created this object, we can assign it to some new properties called:

1. `standardAppearance`
2. `compactAppearance`
3. `scrollEdgeAppearance` (this one in particular was probably the cause probably of my bug)

I post an example of it as an extension:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func setupLarge() {
        // ... Set up here your tintColor, isTranslucent and other properties if you need

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            prefersLargeTitles = true
            //largeTitleTextAttributes = ...Set your attributes
        }

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.backgroundColor = barTintColor
            appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

            standardAppearance = appearance
            compactAppearance = appearance
            scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept your answer so that it can help others

Comment: Sure! But I can in 2 days, for now I still can't